# Screen rotation problem

Tags: gnome, laptop, screen, hp, display-rotation

I was using the Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 daily build from about a month ago.

Surprisingly, auto rotation on my laptop worked out of the box.

Today I have installed a proper release of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 and auto rotation does not work at all. Whenever I try to move my laptop it goes into plane mode.

I wonder if there is a way to bring auto rotation back? Clearly the OS is able to do it.

I use:

- clean install of Ubuntu Gnome 17.04
- HP Spectre x360
- Intel HD 520 graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed GNOME into Xubuntu just to try it out. The only difference I can think of is that before (when it worked) I used the `lightdm` display manager, and in an actual Ubuntu GNOME installation (what I have now) uses GNOME's own `gdm` display manager. I'm afraid of breaking my current installation, but installing lightdm might fix it. **Do be careful before doing this.** I've not tried it myself.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)